# How to use r googledrive to list files in folder that was shared with me?

Tags: r, list, file, tidyverse, drive

I can list files in a folder on my drive like so:

```
# folder in My Drive > My_Folder

my_folder_url = "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1mrrXtFggFMBynT-pmhHtx264mYn0XaeG"

files <- googledrive::drive_ls(path = my_folder_url)

# working!
```

This works if the folder shows up on my drive under My Drive > My_Folder.

It does not work if the folder was shared with me and lives in Shared with me > My_Folder

```
# folder in Shared with me > My_Folder
my_folder_url = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17iA3jM8K0BGEDbkHjfJq5WY7X2dsSfC4"

files <- googledrive::drive_ls(path = my_folder_url)

# ERROR
```

I am getting the following error
[image]

It says that the shared drive is not found. Not sure what they are referring to there. It is not the folder I attempted to find as it has a different ID.

The [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/googledrive/versions/2.0.0/topics/drive_ls) says "If it (path) is a shared drive or is a folder on a shared drive, it must be passed as a dribble", but this did not work.

```
my_folder_url = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17iA3jM8K0BGEDbkHjfJq5WY7X2dsSfC4"

files <- googledrive::drive_ls(path = googledrive::as_dribble(my_folder_url)

# SAME ERROR
```

I also tried arguments corpus = "allDrives" and q = "sharedWithMe"

```
my_folder_url = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17iA3jM8K0BGEDbkHjfJq5WY7X2dsSfC4"

files <- googledrive::drive_ls(path = my_folder_url, corpus = "allDrives")

# SAME ERROR

files <- googledrive::drive_ls(path = my_folder_url, q = "sharedWithMe")

# SAME ERROR
```

What am I missing?